# Ajax.ActionLink value lost

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have **ajax.actionLink** in my view.
That i used to render a partial view again and again.
And my partial view hold two textBoxe and one dropdown 
When i click that link partial view is rendered sucessfully and then manually i entered some value in that form
And when i use to click again on that link(in that case) i dont want to loose previous data filled by me
Is there any way?????

```
<div id="newPackage">@Ajax.ActionLink("Create New Package", "createClientPackage", "test",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
            HttpMethod = "post",
            UpdateTargetId = "newPackage"
        })</div>
       <div id="package"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no fan of built in Ajax Helpers so I will give you an example with pure jQuery:

```
$("#newPackage").click(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("createClientPackage", "test")',
        success: function(data) { 

            var $newPart = $(data);
            $newPart.appendTo("#package");
        }
    });
});
```

Wrote it with notepad but should work.

Also, see the below blog post for a sample scenario:

[Working With JQuery Ajax API on ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - Power of JSON, JQuery and ASP.NET MVC Partial Views](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/working-with-jquery-ajax-api-on-asp-net-mvc-3-0-power-of-json-jquery-and-asp-net-mvc-partial-views)